# Runnable interface start method

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that there are two ways to write threads in Java:

- Method A: Extend Thread class
- Method B: Use Runnable interface.

When you extend `Thread` class, and then later on call `start()` method on that thread, the implementation of `start()` was defined in `Thread` class.

But when you implement Runnable interface, you only have definition of `start()` method and not the body.

So how is is that when you invoke `start()` method using method B, does Java know what to do?

Comment: The `Runnable` interface does not declare a `start()` method.

Comment: `new Thread(new ImplementationOfRunnable()).start()`....

Comment: Because the `Thread` class knows what to do based on how it was constructed (provided you don't break it by overriding `start()` or something ... rarely should you ever be extending `Thread`)

Comment: It's almost as though the writers of `Thread` knew the `Runnable` interface methods, but how could that be?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the `Runnable` implementation in isolation; you pass it to a thread that calls the `run` method for you. This happens too when passing the runnable (or callable) to a thread pool.

You can see the mechanics in the source for the `Thread` class.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot run a `Runnable` with a `start()` method as unlike `Thread` class it doesn't have a `start`. Instead you can do any of the following

```
    B b = new new B();  // assuming B implements Runnable
    new Thread(b).start();
            // or
    b.run();
```

But there is significant difference between the above two ways.

in the first case there is another thread created to perform the Runnable task. But in the second case there is no external thread created.

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually override the `start` method when using threads, you override the `run` method.

The `Thread` class already has a default implementation of `run` that runs a `Runnable` if there is one bound to the `Thread`.

When you override the `run` method, you basically say that you don't want the `Thread` to run the `Runnable` but instead execute your own procedures.